# React-bootstrap-typeeahead filterBy warning

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using react-bootstrap-typeahead to allow users to search through a list of people based on their names or emails. I'm following the custom filtering example [here](https://ericgio.github.io/react-bootstrap-typeahead/#custom-filtering) with the data fields option, and everything is working fine, except that I'm receiving multiple warnings in the console with each letter I type:

```
Warning: [react-bootstrap-typeahead] Fields passed to `filterBy` should have string values. Value will be converted to a string; results may be unexpected.
```

Below are the options I'm passing to the component:

```
const options = [
{displayName: "John Doe", fullName: "John Henry Doe", email: "john_doe@gmail.com"}, 
{displayName: "Jane Smith", fullName: "Jane Susan Smith", email: "jane_smith@gmail.com"} 
]
```

And here is my code for the typeahead itself:

```
render() {
const {
  isLoading,
} = this.state;
const filterByFields = ['email', 'displayName'];
return (
  <TypeAheadSearchWrapper>
    <Typeahead
      filterBy={filterByFields}
      labelKey="displayName"
      options={options}
      placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      minLength={3}
      onInputChange={this.handleTextInput}
      isLoading={isLoading}
      renderMenuItemChildren={option => (
        <div>
          {option.displayName}
          <div className="sub-text">{option.email}</div>
        </div>
      )}
    />
  </TypeAheadSearchWrapper>
);
}
}
```

I'm following the example exactly, and the items in 'filterByFields' are in fact strings. Any idea how to get rid of this warning?

Comment: The code you've posted above doesn't trigger a warning. Can you post a live example (jsfiddle, codepen, etc)? My best guess is that one or more of your data options has a non-string value somewhere, like maybe an undefined email.

Answer (score 2):

The [doc](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/docs/Rendering.md) states that

> The labelKey prop specifies the string that will be used for searching and rendering options and selections.

Since you want to search users by their full name and email you'll need to provide them as the labelKey

```
<Typeahead labelKey={option => `${option.fullName} ${option.email}`}/>
```